# A issue to use URL template tag in django

Tags: django

I am currently learning Django. When I apply a url template tag, I found that the output of the url tag is not what I expected. I have read the Django Documents, but it does not help.

```
<a href ="{% url 'movies:detail'  movie.id %">{{ movie.title }}</a>
```

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'movies'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:movie_id>', views.detail, name='detail')
]
```

The output of the url tag is localhost/movies/%7B%%20url%20'movies:detail'%20movie.id%20%

which is not as I expected: localhost:8000/movies/1

Comment: You have not closed your `url` tag, You need to close it with `%}`

Answer (score 0):

Modify lines as follow:

```
<a href ="{% url 'movies:detail'  movie.id %}">{{ movie.title }}</a>
```

...

```
path('movies/<int:movie_id>/', views.detail, name='detail')
```